# HTML - navbar across pages (with PHP include) with dropdown menus?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to outsource my navbar into a file that I can read in/include in all other pages for my project. I saw that PHP's `include` can work, but doing that made my whole menu static and lost the dropdown menu.

Here's my simplified page, with the navbar with the dropdown menu:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="homepage">
        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <div id="header">

                    <!-- Nav -->
                        <nav id="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">1 &rarr;</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">thing 1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">thing 2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">thing 3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">not dropdown</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the javascript that helps with the dropdown:

```
    $('#nav > ul').dropotron({
        mode: 'fade',
        speed: 350,
        noOpenerFade: true,
        alignment: 'center'
    });
```

When I put my navbar code into a separate file & try `<?php include("nav.php");?>`, the dropdown part doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've also tried it with js and had the same problem where it loads fine but lacks the dropdown:

```
<nav id="nav">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script>
            $(function(){
            $("#nav").load("nav.html");
            });
       </script> 
</nav>
```

Getting that or the PHP way to work would be great.

Comment: Are you including your javascript for the dropdown across each page also?

Comment: are your inside a document.ready function with your code?

Comment: Do you have PHP running on your web server? What errors are you getting in the browser's console or your server's error logs?

Comment: 1st I would use require instead of include.  Check the difference.  Then post what you tried and we will have a look.  At present, you are asking us to code it for you.

Comment: @Conor yes, I include it at the bottom of each page

Comment: @j08691 right now I'm just running it locally. I'm not getting any errors, and when I inspect the navbar, it shows that there is a `ul` but doesn't have the hover-to-drop capabilities.

Comment: If you're running it locally without a web server to process the PHP then how do you think the PHP is going to work?

Comment: @Toxide82 not 100% sure what that is, but I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work! In `index.html` I used the following where the navbar was originally:

```
<nav id="nav">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(function(){
    $("#nav").load("nav.html");
    });
</script> 
</nav>
```

And THEN (this did the trick), I re-included by js files in the `nav.html`:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#">1 &rarr;</a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">thing 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">thing 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">thing 3</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       <li><a href="#">not dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

So I have the js files both at the end of my `index.html